# Sorting a table by multiple factors

Tags: c++, sorting

So I am in the situation where I have to write a class to sort a table of elements. I want to sort on columns only but I want to do multi level sorting so for example

```
a 2
b 1
b 2
a 1
```

the first sort would be on the first column and end up like so

```
a 2
a 1
b 1
b 2
```

Now I want to sort on the second column without clobbering the first column sort already so like so

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
```

My idea was that for each level of sorting that I go down I keep track of the ranges that need to be sorted on. So before the initial sort my ranges would be like so:
`range = 0..3` and then my next level would be `range=0..1,2..3`. I am not sure if this would be very efficient so I wanted to get opinions on any other ways which this could be done.

EDIT: I need to take an arbitrary amount of columns possibly with custom comparators for each column

Comment: Why not to sort everything in one shot?

Comment: Look into a stable sort such as `std::stable_sort`.

Answer (score 4):

You can store each row in an `std::pair<char, int>`, put those in an `std::vector<std::pair<char, int>>`, and use the `std::sort` function to give you the required sorting. You don't have to write any classes or algorithms of your own.

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> table;

// read data into `table`
....

// sort the table
std::sort(table.begin(), table.end());

// print out contents
for (const auto& p : table)
{
  std::cout << p.first << " " << p.last << "\n";
}
```

This can be generalised to more columns by using `std::tuple` (or `std::tr1::tuple` or `boost::tuple` if you are stuck with an old implementation of C++). `tuples` have lexicographical comparisons that work in the same way as those of `pair`. If you need a different ordering, you can pass your own comparison function as a 3rd argument to `std::sort`.

Comment: No I can't cause I'm not sure how many columns I am going to get and each column can have a custom comparator. I'll edit my problem with such details

Comment: @legion You need to specify your problem better.

Comment: @legion then just use std::tuple and write a custom comparator if necessary

Comment: @legion then use boost::tuple, or write a `struct` or `class` and one comparator which compares fields in order of priority

Comment: @slava I appreciate the input but I can't do one comparator it will not work in my case

Comment: @legion one comparator will work, it just needs to compare all fields in order.

Comment: @legion I really don't think you need one comparator per column. If you really think you do, then you should explain it clearly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::pair<char, int> a[] = 
    { 
        { 'a', 2 },
        { 'b', 1 },
        { 'b', 2 },
        { 'a', 1 }
    };

    for ( const auto &p : a )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &p : a )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a   2
b   1
b   2
a   1

a   1
a   2
b   1
b   2
```

instead of `std::pair` you can use `std::tuple` for multiple columns. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>

int main() 
{
    std::tuple<char, int, bool> a[] = 
    { 
        std::make_tuple( 'a', 2, true ),
        std::make_tuple( 'b', 1, false ),
        std::make_tuple( 'b', 2, true ),
        std::make_tuple( 'a', 1, true ),
        std::make_tuple( 'a', 2, false ),
        std::make_tuple( 'a', 1, false )
    };

    for ( const auto &t : a )
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>( t ) << '\t' 
                  << std::get<1>( t ) << '\t'
                  << std::get<2>( t ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &t : a )
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>( t ) << '\t' 
                  << std::get<1>( t ) << '\t'
                  << std::get<2>( t ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a   2   1
b   1   0
b   2   1
a   1   1
a   2   0
a   1   0

a   1   0
a   1   1
a   2   0
a   2   1
b   1   0
b   2   1
```

If you have to sort an array of structures with different data members then you can build a tuple from these data members and use it in a predicate of `std::sort`.